# Post Deployment Integration Testing in Mule

Tags: maven, testing, mule, integration, munit

I have an application for which I have an Integration Test suite written using Munit. I am deploying this to CloudHub Using Jenkins.

How can I execute the test cases post-deployment?

Is there any command line tool that can  I make use of or it can done using maven or Jenkins?

Comment: I just realised that my answer may not be appropriate. You said that you are deploying your app to CloudHub via Jenkins, so you mean you want to run the integration tests right after the Jenkins deployment on CloudHub ? If so, how are you currently deploying on CloudHub with Jenkins? (using Maven, a script, anything else?)

Comment: If your project currently uses Maven for any of these tasks, it may be a good idea to include your pom.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your Maven build to deploy your Mule application during the `pre-integration-test` phase, run your tests during the `integration-test` phase and optionally undeploy during the `post-integration-test` phase. You can use something like:

```
<plugins>

    ...

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <deploymentType>cloudhub</deploymentType>
            <!-- muleVersion is the runtime version as it appears on the CloudHub interface -->
            <muleVersion>3.7.0</muleVersion>
            <username>myUsername</username>
            <password>myPassword</password>
            <redeploy>true</redeploy>
            <environment>Production</environment>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>deploy</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>undeploy</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>undeploy</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${munit.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <munittest>.*-unit-test-suite.xml</munittest>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>it-test</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <munittest>.*-integration-test-suite.xml</munittest>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <coverage>
                    <runCoverage>false</runCoverage>>
                </coverage>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    ...

</plugins>
```

See the [Mule Maven plugin documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mule-maven-plugin#running-integration-tests) for details on how to configure the deployment on CloudHub.

EDIT: as you are using MUnit to run your tests, you will have to configure the MUnit Maven Plugin to run your integration tests, taking care of differentiating them from eventual Unit Tests. See [MUnit Maven Support](https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/v/1.3/munit-maven-support). Your MUnit Integration Tests should run on the `integration-test` phase. If you have trouble configuring your build let me know in the comment I'll edit accordingly.

EDIT2: I updated my answer to provide a working example of MUnit Maven configuration able to perform both unit-testing and integration-testing.

There are 2 executions configured:

- The first one will run on `test` phase and use only MUnit tests matching the `.*-unit-test-suite.xml` regex (via the `munittest` parameter)
- The second one will run on `integration-test` and use only tests matching the `.*-integration-test-suite.xml` regex.

You'll then have to name your Unit Tests and Integration Tests according to these patterns to make sure they are launched in the proper order. That's an example of course, the important thing is making sure your Unit Tests and Integration Tests are differentiated and launched at the proper moment - as it is done with the Maven Failsafe and Surefire Plugin using respectively `*Test` and `*IT` classes.

If you only have Integration Tests to run, you can skip this complicated configuration and just use the integration-test execution without the `munittest` parameter.

In a nutshell, your build should then do something like:

1. Run Unit Tests via MUnit (`unit-test` execution during `test` phase)
2. Deploy your application on Cloudhub (`deploy` execution during `pre-integration-test` phase
3. Run Integration Tests via MUnit (`it-test` execution during `integration-test` phase)
4. Undeploy your application from Cloudhub (`undeploy` execution during `post-integration-test` phase

If your are not familiar with phases and executions, read [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pierre. How can we try this inside Anypoint Studio?

Comment: To launch integration tests with Maven the best way to go is to run the `mvn clean verify` command. As you are using MUnit, you should include in your pom.xml a proper MUnit configuration for the Munit Maven Plugin - something I missed in my answer, I'll edit it. However I don't know of any practical way of running integration tests with Eclipse or Studio, usually only unit tests are run through IDEs. Best to use a terminal or shell, or via Jenkins as you may already be doing.

Comment: Thanks Pierre for instant help.

Comment: Yes, I am using Jenkins to deploy this in cloud hub. As you said I can run the test using the command line. Also, I need one more help how can I test the network connectivity in the munit while doing integration testing.

Comment: If I am having AMQP connector I want to test the behaviour when it's available and unavailable. It would be a great help if you share any sample test script for that. I don't want to mock the behaviour I want to test it in real time.

Comment: I think its best if you answer another question regarding that matter if you have a specific issue ;)

Comment: Can you paste the sample pom.xml config to run Munit Test during the integration-test phase? I will try that out.

Comment: Pierre below is the way that I configured for munit

Comment: `<executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>`

Comment: I updated my answer again to provide a complete example of Munit Maven Plugin configuration for integration and unit testing. Let me know if you have any issue and if that's work for you ;)

Comment: Do you have any sample for Integration tests?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The pom sample shows an example for integration tests. What do you mean?